# MongoDB: How to query documents by rounding a specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's suppose there is the following collection of documents in MongoDB:

```
Scores

{ _id: 1, value: 3.25 }
{ _id: 2, value: 1.37 }
{ _id: 3, value: 2.48 }
{ _id: 4, value: 2.5 }
```

I would like to query documents with the rounded `value` of `3`.
So it will return `{ _id: 1, value: 3.25 }` and `{ _id: 4, value: 2.5 }` only.

The Node.js query would be something like `db.collection('scores').find({...})`

What do I need to put in the query?

Comment: will this work `{ value: { $gte: 2.5, $lt: 3.5 } }`?

Comment: I just need a general query to pass any value.

Comment: Anything stops you to programmatically calculate upper and lower bounds from the "any value" before querying mongo?

Comment: I just wanted a built-in query operator, it would be nice to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it possible to directly using any query operators,

you can prepare condition on the client-side by number's minimum and maximum value boundry, just prepare a function like,

```
function getValueCondition(n) {
  return { 
    $gte: Math.round(n) - 0.5, 
    $lt: Math.round(n) + 0.5
  };
}
```

You query would be and get condition,

```
let inputNumber = 3;
db.collection('scores').find({ 
  value: getValueCondition(inputNumber)
});
```